# Pop an AlertDialog from AlarmManger

Tags: android, dialog, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog, alarmmanager

I'm trying to make the BroadcastReceiver Run an AlertDialog and it's just skipping the call to the Dialog Method(And throwing into the catch exception):
My BroadcastReceiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.con = context;
        try 
        {            
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR TAG");
            //Acquire the lock
            wl.acquire();

            intent.getExtras();
            new StringBuilder();
            wl.release();
            String[] a ={"a","b"};
            create(context, a); //The Dialog Call
            setOnetimeTimer(con);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Hurray!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
             Toast.makeText(context, "Error,broadcastReciver"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
```

And Here is the `create()` Method:(That Create the Dialog)
    public static void create (Context context,String[] descriptions) {

```
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle("Random String");
        builder.setMessage(descriptions[rn.nextInt(2)]);
        //builder.setMessage("test");
        builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Close",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

Thanks!
Edit:Don't say me to put it in an activity and run the activity,because i don't want it to open my app,i want it to be above the opened app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Before Edit)1.i Called the class `Dialog` so when the Intent tried to call to `Dialog.class` it's called to in System class `Dialog`.
2.I used:
[How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)
to make the Activity Transparent and i used no `ContentView` so only the Dialog pop-up above the already open activity.

Answer (score 0):

Without setting the calendar's longer duration fields (e.g., year), it appears that you are setting the alarm before the current time. Try something like this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTES, 23*60 + 58);
```